# Is this a simple or compound sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

> The water will gradually evaporate **leaving the sugar juice to solidify in the pan**

The ambiguous part to me is at the phrase: *leaving the sugar...* Is that a compound sentence of a clause (*The water... evaporate*) and a gerund phrase (*leaving the sugar...*) which elided the conjunction AND between them? Or it is a simple sentence, the gerund phrase play some kind of grammatical role after the verb *evaporate*. Which grammar rule do you think about that sentence? Please explain.

Comment: It's a 'complex' sentence. There are three subordinate (dependent) clauses: (1) "gradually evaporate", (2) "leaving the sugar juice to solidify in the pan" and (3) "to solidify in the pan", which is embedded within (2). Thus: "The water will [gradually evaporate] [leaving the sugar juice [to solidify in the pan]]".

Comment: what do you think if I added the conjunction "so" to connect them together: "The water will gradually evaporate so leaving the sugar juice to solidify in the pan"

Comment: It wouldn't change the analysis. The connective "so" would be part of the clause "so leaving the sugar juice to solidify in the pan", still an adjunct in clause structure.